# Is there a way to change __mro__ in Python Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

Is there any way to replace the default `__mro__` attribute Python creates for a class? I'd like to have a different one made by me in order for resolution. 
Now when I try to assign something to `__mro__` I get a "Read only attribute" exception.

Comment: You can't change it directly.  Typically if you want a different MRO, you would define a new class that inherits from other classes in the order you want.  Can you give more detail about what you want to achieve and why?

Comment: A metaclass with a custom `__getattribute__` could use its own method resolution order for ordinary attribute lookup, but it wouldn't do anything for special method lookup. This is probably best solved by approaching the problem from a direction that doesn't require you to do this. Why do you want to change the MRO?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea that is likely to lead to really confusing, hard to debug code.  What are you trying to accomplish with this exactly?

Comment: On the fly? No. But you can customize the MRO by overriding the [`mro` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro) of the metaclass.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to change object's class or rewrite it's mro:

```py
def upgrade_class(obj, old_class, new_class):
    if obj.__class__ is old_class:
        obj.__class__ = new_class
    else:
        mro = obj.__class__.mro()

        def replace(cls):
            if cls is old_class:
                return new_class
            else:
                return cls

        bases = tuple(map(replace, mro[1:]))
        old_base_class = obj.__class__
        new_class = type(old_base_class.__name__, bases, dict(old_base_class.__dict__))
        obj.__class__ = new_class
```